# Angular 6 - Nested Components inside Custom Modal Window

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, angular6

I followed [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/25/angular-6-custom-modal-window-dialog-box) to create a custom modal. Everything works as supposed except putting other Angular components inside the `<div class="modal-body">`.

The template and CSS of the inserted components loads but the javascript just doesn't work.

**How is it possible to insert working Angular components into such a dialog?**

Comment: I think to get an angular component to work inside, you might need to mention that component as an entry component in the app.module.ts file. So that the component is available to show inside the modal.

Comment: This works, thx! Is it a good practice to put all components needed into `entryComponents`?

Comment: It worked after adding it in entry component? or did u do some other way?

Comment: It worked after adding it in entry component of app.module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all the dynamically called components( those components which we are not mentioned in the template by the template selector) should be added to the entry components. If we do that Angular will instantiate the component for us.

The best practice is to mention the components in the component declarations and if there is any dynamically created components, add them into entry components. Everytime we add components to entry components it cost us the performance. try to reduced the entry components :). Hope I answered your query.